# sort multi-dimension array with longitude and latitude in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array with multi level arrays in it. like:

```
$array = [
    [
        [
            'name' => 'Array-01',
            'phone' => '555',
            'address' => [
                'longitude' => 50.123456, //e.g.
                'latitude' => 37.521456, //e.g.
                'state' => 'LA'
            ]
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Array-02',
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Array-03',
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            'name' => 'Array-01',
            'phone' => '555',
            'address' => [
                'longitude' => 50.123456, //e.g.
                'latitude' => 37.521456, //e.g.
                'state' => 'CA'
            ]
        ],
        [
        [
            'name' => 'Array-02',
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Array-03',
        ]
    ],
];
```

I want to sort second level array by longitude and latitude value.

*There were lots of questions, but I couldn't find them helpful*

**EDIT:**
I want to sort `$array[$index]` by longitude and latitude value in

```
$array[$index][0]['address']
```

*`$index` assumed as array index in loop*

Comment: Can you provide sample of the expected output data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare arrays for sorting purposes (when the arrays contain the same keys!) you can use the spaceship operator `<=>` and simply treat them as *values*; this returns -1, 0, or 1 depending on the comparison result:

```
$array_a = [1];
$array_b = [2];
var_dump($array_a <=> $array_b);

// Ouput: int(-1)
```

Of course we need a *user defined function* for the sorting algorithm so `usort` is our friend:

```
$array = [
    [2],
    [1],
    [3],
];

usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    $a[0] <=> $b[0];
});

print_r($array);

/*

Output:

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
        )
)

*/
```

However, your arrays are second level so we need to iterate through each of the first level with `foreach`:

```
$array = [
    [
        [
            'name' => 'Array-01',
            'address' => [
                'longitude' => rand(1,1000), 
                'latitude' => rand(1,1000)
            ]
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Array-02',
            'address' => [
                'longitude' => rand(1,1000),
                'latitude' => rand(1,1000)
            ]
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Array-03',
            'address' => [
                'longitude' => rand(1,1000),
                'latitude' => rand(1,1000)
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            'name' => 'Array-01',
            'address' => [
                'longitude' => rand(1,1000),
                'latitude' => rand(1,1000)
            ]
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Array-02',
            'address' => [
                'longitude' => rand(1,1000),
                'latitude' => rand(1,1000)
            ]
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'Array-03',
            'address' => [
                'longitude' => rand(1,1000),
                'latitude' => rand(1,1000)
            ]
        ]
    ],
];


// rand used to generate random example values array 
// printed here to show the generated (unsorted) values.
print_r($array);

foreach ($array as &$arr)
    usort($arr, function($a, $b){
        return $a["address"] <=> $b["address"];
    });

print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
// Unsorted array
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Array-01
                    [address] => Array
                        (
                            [longitude] => 440
                            [latitude] => 185
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Array-02
                    [address] => Array
                        (
                            [longitude] => 253
                            [latitude] => 944
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Array-03
                    [address] => Array
                        (
                            [longitude] => 388
                            [latitude] => 938
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Array-01
                    [address] => Array
                        (
                            [longitude] => 763
                            [latitude] => 236
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Array-02
                    [address] => Array
                        (
                            [longitude] => 772
                            [latitude] => 476
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Array-03
                    [address] => Array
                        (
                            [longitude] => 715
                            [latitude] => 815
                        )

                )

        )

)

// Sorted array
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Array-02
                    [address] => Array
                        (
                            [longitude] => 253
                            [latitude] => 944
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Array-03
                    [address] => Array
                        (
                            [longitude] => 388
                            [latitude] => 938
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Array-01
                    [address] => Array
                        (
                            [longitude] => 440
                            [latitude] => 185
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Array-03
                    [address] => Array
                        (
                            [longitude] => 715
                            [latitude] => 815
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Array-01
                    [address] => Array
                        (
                            [longitude] => 763
                            [latitude] => 236
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Array-02
                    [address] => Array
                        (
                            [longitude] => 772
                            [latitude] => 476
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: @Milad I'm not quite sure what you mean? The edit is what this code does? Perhaps you could post some sample before and after data?